# How to identify if the pushpin is visible in the current view/zoom of bingMaps or not? if not visible setView to Location of the pushpin?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using Bing Maps V8 and As per ask, I've to move/pan the bing map to set the visibility of the pushpin. Based on the pushpin location we can directly set the view as shown below but I've adjust/move the bing map only if the current view of bing maps doesn't have the pushpin visible to the naked eye.

```
this.map.setView({
     center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(pin.lat, pin.long),
});
```

Could you please share your thoughts on how to identify whether the pin is visible in the current view or not?

Regards & Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the bounding box of the map, then check to see if it contains your pushpins location. If it doesn't update the map view. Here is a code block that does this.

```
var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {});
var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(45, -110), null);
map.entities.push(pushpin);

//Get the bounding box of the current map view.
var bounds = map.getBounds();

//Check to see if the bounding box contains the pushpins location. 
//And if it doesn't, center the map.
if(!bounds.contains(pushpin.getLocation())) {
    map.setView({
        center: pushpin.getLocation()
    });
}
```